Cannot access files local path after mounting local path to Jupyter running inside of a docker container
I have a folder called "Data" in my working directory and I supposedly mounted this folder to the Jupyter running inside of a docker container. I can store files but I cannot read files stored in the Data folder.
The docker image I want to run is called jupyterml2.
I have tried many things, including:

docker run --rm -p 8888:8888 -v /Data:/home/jovian/work jupyterml2
docker run -it -v /Data:/home/jovyan/work --user root -e CHOWN_HOME=yes -e CHOWN_HOME_OPTS='-R' -p 8888:8888 jupyterml2
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -v /Data:/work --rm --name jupyter jupyterml2
docker run -p 8888:8888 -v /Data:/home/jovian/work jupyterml2

